# Trend in residual plot

Tags: regression, residuals, trend, rms

I have a regression problem: I have to predict for how long (in days) a house will stay in the market before that someone will buy it.

To predict how many days the house stays in the market I am fitting an xgboost to the data that I have, and testing my output on an unseen dataset.

My residual plot looks like this
[image]

Clearly a trend is visible (the difference between the real and the prediction gets bigger as the house stays more in the market).

I also plotted the RMSE for the houses sold each day
[image]
Also here you can see that the error increases the more a house stays in the market.

- RMSE:50.69616116149248 days
- RMSE (for houses that stay in the market
  < 42 days):22.68122788199007 days
- RMSE (for houses that stay in the
  market >= 42 days):108.39701898105788 days

In the following graph you can see the predictions vs actual value
[image]
In the dataset there are a lot of houses that stay in the market for few days...

I think that from the graphs I can deduct that there is something wrong.... Could you help me interpreting and finding the way to improve my results?

Comment: If you visually inspect scatterplots of each independent variable vs. the dependent variable, there may be some obvious data transform that becomes apparent. This exercise has the advantage of being both easy to perform and relatively fast.

Comment: Hi James, unfortunately most of my independent variables are categorical with 4 categories at most....I dont see anything :)